# Can parent window access messages sent from popup window opened from parent window child iframe?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, iframe, google-chrome-extension

**Context**

I'm working on a WebExtension (currently only for Chrome) that appends an iframe into a website. The parent window can be any website that my users may visit. The source of iframe is a local extension url (e.g. `chrome-extension://aioneahjkkfbncifpekfheecjplgheru/widget/index.html`).

I want to do social authentication (Facebook, Twitter, Google). That's why I need to open a popup window from that child iframe which will authenticate the user and will send callback authentication token back to the iframe using `postMessage`.

**Question**

Is there any way that the parent window containing iframe can intercept that login token?

What I'm most worried is that someone will maliciously create some website that will intercept authentication tokens whenever my users: (1) will visit that website, (2) use my extension that will inject the iframe into that website, (3) use social authentication to sign in from that iframe.

**Visual Representation**

[image: Can I Haz Tokenz?]

Comment: postMessage second parameter is the extension origin, right? So the site won't see it.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Yep, I'm using the extension url "chrome-extension://<id>" for the origin check. But I was wondering if in this case checking only for origin will suffice.

Comment: Upvote just for the illustration.

Comment: Have you considered using `chrome.identity`?

Comment: @Xan haha thanks, I've used draw.io for it. And as for `chrome.identity` - I'm first seeing this and it looks like it should be very good for my use case. Thanks! However I still have some other parts of my application (not involving authentication) using the iframe window popup approach + switching to `chrome.identity` will involve a lot more additional added complexity and work from my side. So I'm still curious about the answers.

Comment: I guess it would be helpful if you show your popup-opening and messaging code.